# while running the query i am getting string indices must be integers .how to solve this issue?

Tags: python

while trying to run the below  code i am getting error as 'string indices must be integers' how to solve this?

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/queryformat=geojson' +\
    '&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02'

lat=[]
lng=[]

for d in data:
    lat.append(d['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
    lng.append(d['geometry']['coordinates'][1])
```

Comment: Provide some sample 'data' which you're hashing. Is data 2d?

Comment: so `data` is a 4d array? you may want to use dictionaries. or make use of numpy

Comment: {u'geometry': {u'coordinates': [-168.3619, 53.237, 12.1], u'type': u'Point'},
 u'id': u'ak12383570',
 this is the sample data

Comment: i am using the dictionaries to fetch the data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're filling the data var with since you did not include that code but this works.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
url='https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02'

data = requests.get(url)
data = data.json()
lat=[]
lng=[]
for d in data['features']:
    lat.append(d['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
    lng.append(d['geometry']['coordinates'][1])
```

I suspect you were not selecting the data from 'features'.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import os
>>> url='https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02'
>>>
>>> data = requests.get(url)
>>> data.json().keys()
dict_keys(['type', 'metadata', 'features', 'bbox'])
```

Failing example, notice the missing 'features' key on data.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import os
>>> url='https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-10-01&endtime=2016-10-02'
>>>
>>> data = requests.get(url)
>>> data = data.json()
>>> lat=[]
>>> lng=[]
>>> for d in data:
...     lat.append(d['geometry']['coordinates'][0])
...     lng.append(d['geometry']['coordinates'][1])
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
>>>
```